# Android Navigation Drawer all content disapear

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-xml

I just trying add navigation drawer but content not showing in activity and drawer can't be sliding. But when i put TextView inside NavigationView it will show.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    // Toolbar

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"/>
    
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add something as a childview to Implement Material navigation drawers as per latest material design guidelines.
Material Guidelines says this:
Implementing navigation drawers is the most common use for NavigationView, this section guides you on how to use NavigationView in that context.

1. Wrap your activity's content in a DrawerLayout. In the example
   below, the activity's content is the CoordinatorLayout.
2. Keep your main content as the first child of that DrawerLayout.
3. Add your NavigationView with `android:layout_gravity="start|left"` and
   `android:height="match_parent"`.

Assuming your Activity's content is in a CoordinatorLayout you may have something like this:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|left"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Read it Here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view)